# Which monitor would be better to programming?

Tags: monitors, multiple-monitors

I have a two options.

1. two [`dell P2417H`](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-p2417h-monitor/pd) 23'
2. one [`LG 32MA68HY-P`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IA9FXAO) 32' (window split available)

I'm developing web(front and back) and usually using vim and sublime text.
I'll connect to my 2017 13' MBP.

Which one is better? Recently, I've never used monitor. So I don't imagine which one is better to me.

Comment: The choice is a very personal one. Being a web developer myself, my experience has been that Mac devs chose a bigger screen over two smaller ones while Windows devs chose the opposite.

Comment: What's your budget? Target resolution and size? Do you care particularly about color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these monitors are 1920 x 1080, 60 Hz monitors. The primary difference is their physical size. The benefit of the larger monitor is that (assuming you would have each at the same distance from your eyes) you will be able to lower the display scale on the larger screen and potentially fit more in view.

Note: there will be substantial loss in visual fidelity. The smaller monitor will give you about 50% greater [pixel density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) than the 32" screen. The flipside is that obviously the larger monitor will be more comfortable to look at from a further distance, and for tasks that require less fine detail (such as watching non-bluray quality movies) the larger monitor will just be more pleasing to look at.

[Pixel density calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/pixels-per-inch)

You must determine whether the increased size is a better value for you than the bump in pixel density.

Comment: Agreeing with this.  Also, it may be important to you that the monitor can rotate on its mount 90 degrees.  I don't do so much web dev, but I do some, and having a portrait screen next to a landscape screen makes it much easier to work with markup languages (HTML, XML, JSON) and chase down code in huge code blocks in .Net stuff.